# Parse Exception Error

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink, parseexception

I am getting the below error on startup in informa.jar. I tried looking for this exception but couldn't find anything. Could you please provide any pointers.

```
de.nava.informa.utils.FeedManagerException: ParseException: Error on line 57: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
        at de.nava.informa.utils.FeedManagerEntry.retrieveFeed(FeedManagerEntry.java:160)
        at de.nava.informa.utils.FeedManagerEntry.<init>(FeedManagerEntry.java:86)
        at de.nava.informa.utils.FeedManager.addFeed(FeedManager.java:262)
        at com.ubizen.og.reportcenter.news.InformaNewsProvider.addFeed(InformaNewsProvider.java:139)
        at
```

Thanks,
Praseel

Comment: I don't know what `informa` is but, error message tells that there is some xml parsing involved which is failing because of unterminated link tag somewhere in your configuration

Comment: The error looks pretty specific.  You have unmatched tags in your XML.

Comment: Less details to resolve something.

Comment: Informa.jar is a third party jar and this error is displayed in the console on start up